# bad performance with SWT Combo in table

Tags: java, performance, memory-leaks, combobox, swt

I'm having a performance problem with combos in a table.
When I start the application, everything is just fine.
I can change the value of the combos and the reaction of the table is ok.
But when I clear the table and refill it, it seems that there is a catastrophic loss of performance.
When I try to select one row from the table, it takes about 1-2 sec until it is selected.
When I hit the "Reset Table"-Button 5-10 times, the row selection takes 5-6 sec.

First I thought I have to dispose everything after using. But this didn't changed anything.
I've tried it with textboxes, too. The same problem. 
First time the performance is on an acceptable level. hitting the reset-button 
--> very bad performance

Here an example for this problem:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TableEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;

public class Test {
private static Table table;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    table = new Table(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION );
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    column.setText("1");
    column.setWidth(70);
    column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    column.setText("2");
    column.setWidth(70);
    column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    column.setText("3");
    column.setWidth(70);
    fillTable();
    Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea();
    table.setBounds(clientArea.x, clientArea.y, 250, 300);
    shell.setSize(400, 400);
    Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setBounds(10, 320, 150, 25);
    button.setText("Reset Table");
    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener(){

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            resetTable();
        }

    });
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

public static void addComboToCell(final int intgPEditCell) {
    final TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);
    // The editor must have the same size as the cell and must
    // not be any smaller than 50 pixels.
    editor.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT;
    editor.grabHorizontal = true;
    editor.minimumWidth = 50;
    // editing the second column
    table.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // Clean up any previous editor control
            Control oldEditor = editor.getEditor();
            if (oldEditor != null)
                oldEditor.dispose();

            // Identify the selected row
            TableItem item = (TableItem) e.item;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            // The control that will be the editor must be a child of the
            // Table
            Combo newEditor = new Combo(table, SWT.NONE);
            // SWT.NONE);
            newEditor.setText(item.getText(intgPEditCell));
            newEditor.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {
                public void modifyText(ModifyEvent me) {
                    Combo combo = (Combo) editor.getEditor();
                    editor.getItem()
                            .setText(intgPEditCell, combo.getText());
                }
            });
             newEditor.setFocus();
            editor.setEditor(newEditor, item, intgPEditCell);
        }
    });
}

public static void resetTable(){
    TableItem[] tableItems = table.getItems();
    for (int i = 0; i < tableItems.length; i++) {
        tableItems[i].dispose();
    }
    Control[] children = table.getChildren();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].dispose();
    }
    table.removeAll();
    fillTable();
}

public static void fillTable(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        TableItem item = new TableItem(table, 0);
        item.setText(0, "0 Item " + i);
        item.setText(1, "1 Item " + i);
        item.setText(2, "2 Item " + i);
        addComboToCell(0);
    }
}
}
```

So my question is how can I improve the performance after refill the table?!
Did I forgot anything or did anything wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance degradation is caused by the `TableEditor`s you are adding. There is one per row, and all of them are listening to table selection events. Hence if an item is selected, there are 50 `TableEditor`s activated, stacked on top of each other. To add to that the `TableEditor` aren't removed in `resetTable` so that each selection of the reset button adds 50 more.

The conecpt of TableEditors in SWT is to have one editor per column or per editor type. On the appropriate occasion, the editor is moved to the right place, initialized with the right values and then shown.

In your case, the `addComboToCell ( 0 )` call needs to be moved to the `main` method, somewhere after the table is created.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was searching for this the last three days and didn't got the answer. Now it works perfectly!